# How do I combine data in two tables in LibreOffice?

Tags: microsoft-excel, database, libreoffice, openoffice-base

I have a spreadsheet with two sheets. SheetA has Customer number and  location, and SheetB has Order number, Customer number. How do I combine the data so that one sheet has Order number and location? Every column of SheetA is unique, but SheetB may have the Customer number show up more than once.

I've a few thousand of these records to do, so doing it by hand isn't really an option. Also is there a way do this via Base (database)? I have this data in Base, but I exported it to spreadsheet to see if it would be of help.

[Here is a sample of my database for download.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByIy1oPKWxtzLXNXQzFOLUNsM3M/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: With LO Base: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690899/merge-2-calc-documents-based-on-common-field/6693113#6693113; regarding LO Calc: https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc%3a_VLOOKUP_function

Comment: So don't use the relationships tool in base in tools dropdown?

Comment: Thanks for those links, they work wonders. Does base use SQL style queries?

Comment: Yes, you can use SQL to define your queries, as well as the desgin view to create a query "visually".